# Boot Loaders deleted, How to restore EFI?

Tags: boot, efi

I accidentally deleted (Don't really know how) all of the boot entries that appeared on `efibootmgr` on a laptop that had no operative systems (I did it from an Ubuntu Live USB).

Now, when i try to start the computer, it says '`Boot Device Not Found, Please Install an Operating System on your Hard Disk`' and it wont even boot from a CD/USB with Windows/Ubuntu.

I tried changing the boot order from the BIOS Settings, disabling secure boot and legacy boot, and reverting to default settings, but nothing seems to work.

I'ts my fault for touching things i dont know enought about, but... Is there any way to Fix this?

The laptop is an HP if it matters.

Thank you.

Comment: What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Comment: What OS is it??

Comment: @Moab Sorry if it looks like that, but i'v been with this problem the whole evening, and most searchs related to 'Boot Device Not Found' just got me to 'Restore BIOS Settings', 'Check if the HDD is correctly plugged in' i did not really found any topic similar to mine, and since i don't really know what exactly went wrong i cannot tune my research.

Comment: @Moab And the Hard Drive is currently Empty, i was using an Ubuntu Live CD but now it does not boot

Comment: Since the hard drive is "empty" it will not boot from that, you need to edit your question to ask why it will not boot from the optical drive using an Ubuntu disc. There has to be an install Operating system on the hard drive to boot from the hard drive. Since you do not know what you did it will be difficult to diagnose.

Comment: You may need to insert a bootable disk and access your firmware's built-in boot manager. How to do this varies greatly from one EFI to another, but it's usually done by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key (usually F8 or above) soon after you power on the computer. With any luck, the firmware will detect the bootable medium and present a menu entry for it.

Comment: @RodSmith The problem was, that the System does not know how to handle any bootable devices like an USB or CD with Windows/Ubuntu

Comment: I understand that. My point is that activating the built-in boot manager may force the system to re-build those missing entries.

Comment: @RodSmith Sorry, i missunderstood, i'll try it ASAP. Thank you.